# Logcat scrolls down to bottom

Tags: android, eclipse

Am trying to walk through the log-cat , but as I scroll up - logcat immediately scrolls dwown to the last, is this a weird problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a button on the logcat display, at the top right.  It looks like an underlined down arrow.  When you mouse-over it, the tooltip reads "Scroll Lock". This will lock the display from scrolling.  Remember to click it again when you want logcat to be updated again.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=5tvz0h&s=6. Here's a link to the image where you can see the black  underlined down arrow as mentioned by RichieACC

Comment: Or just click inside it before scrolling